# Pointers to class fields

Tags: c++, pointers

My task is as follows :

Using pointers to class fields, create menu allowing selection of ice, that Person can buy in Ice shop. Buyer will be charged with waffel and ice costs.

Selection of ice and charging buyers account must be shown in program.

Here's my Person class :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Iceshop {
    const double waffel_price = 1;
public:

}
class Person {
    static int NUMBER;   
    char* name;
    int age;
    const int number;
    double plus, minus;
public:

    class Account {
        int number;
        double resources;

        public:      
            Account(int number, double resources)
                : number(number), resources(resources)
            {}       
    }   

    Person(const char* n, int age)
        : name(strcpy(new char[strlen(n)+1],n)),
            number(++NUMBER), plus(0), minus(0), age(age)
    {}


    Person::~Person(){
        cout << "Destroying resources" << endl;
        delete [] name;
    }   

    friend void show(Person &p);

   int* take_age(){
       return &age;
   }

   char* take_name(){
         return name;      
   }

    void init(char* n, int a) {
        name = n;
        age = a;
    }

    Person& remittance(double d)  { plus += d; return *this; }
    Person& paycheck(double d) { minus += d; return *this; } 
    Account* getAccount();

};

int Person::

Person::Account* Person::getAccount() {
    return new Account(number, plus - minus);
}


void Person::Account::remittance(double d){
    resources = resources + d;
}

void Person::Account::paycheck(double d){
    resources = resources - d;    
}

void show(Person *p){
    cout << "Name: " << p->take_name() << "," << "age: " << p->take_age() << endl; 
}

int main(void) {
    Person *p = new Person;  
    p->init("Mary", 25);

    show(p);

    p->remittance(100);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

How to change this into using pointers to fields ?

```
class Iceshop {
    const double waffel_price;
    int menu_options;
    double[] menu_prices;
    char* menu_names;
    char* name;
public:

    IceShop(char*c)
        : name(strcpy(new char[strlen(n)+1],n)),
                waffel_price(1), menu(0)
    {}

    void init(int[] n){
        menu_options = n;
    }

    void showMenu(Iceshop &i){
        int list;
        list = &i
        char* sorts = i->menu_names;
        int count=0;

        while(count < list){
                cout << count+1 << ")" << sorts[count] << endl;
                ++count;
        }          
    }

    void createMenu(Iceshop *i){
        for(int j=0; j <(i->menu_options), ++j){
                cout << "Ice name: ";
                cin >> i->menu_names[j];
                endl;
                cout << "Ice cost: "
                cin >> i->menu_prices[j];
                endl;
        }
    }

    void chargeClient(Person *p, Iceshop* i, int sel){
        p->remittance( (i->menu_prices[sel])+(i->waffel_price) );        
    }

};
```

Comment: Also to mention, your `showMenu` is extremely evil. I would recommend you telling yourself what do you want to do before touching the keyboard. What you do now could be described as `Pass another Iceshop object to this object, take it's address and iterate while count is less than that address (SIC!)`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to build a menu driven UI. 
Something like this (copy paste from a forum, for more examples search for 'C++ console' menu' or something like it on google.

```
int choice = 0;

while (choice != 4)
{
 cout <<"Enter choice:"<< endl <<
 "1) ice 1" << endl <<
 "2) ice 2" << endl<<
 "3) ice 3" << endl <<
 "4) exit" << endl;

 cin >> choice;

 switch(choice)
 {
  case 1:
  //show menu to buy or cancel
  break;
  case 2:
  //show menu to buy or cancel
  break;
 }
 //etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do. Note that it's not exactly what you're looking for and, well, abstract situation modelling is always tough :)

But I hope this code would make you understand what you have to do.

Also, I am not exactly sure about using pointers to class fields, because this tends to be a situation where pointer usage is superflous.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

// Some abstract type used to measure prices
typedef size_t money_t;

struct Item {
   // Item's name and price
   std::string name;
   money_t price;

   // Could also have something that makes
   // it an item, but this is not necessary

   // This could be anything, because we're actually
   // modelling an abstract situation

   // (...)

   // Note that we don't allow unnamed items
   Item(const std::string& name, const money_t& price = 0) : name(name), price(price) { }

   // Note here that items are treated as 'same' only by names
   // This means we're actually talking about 'logical groups' of items
   bool operator==(const Item& item) const { return name == item.name; }
   bool operator==(const std::string& item_name) const { return name == item_name; }
};

class Store {
private:
   // Store's item storage

   // Note that items actually represent infinite groups
   // of items (in our case store is an abstract store
   // which items simply can't end)
   std::vector<Item> items;

public:
   // Initialize a store that doesn't sell anything
   Store() { }

   // Initialize a store that could sell specified types of items
   Store(const std::vector<Item>& items) : items(items) { }

   // Show what we actually sell in this store
   void EnumerateItems() const {
      for (size_t i = 0; i < items.size(); ++i)
         std::cout << items[i].name << " : " << items[i].price << "\n";
   }

   Item Sell(const std::string& name) const {
      // Find appropriate item in the item list
      std::vector<Item>::const_iterator what = std::find(items.begin(), items.end(), name);

      // If nothing found, throw an exception
      if (what == items.end()) {
         throw std::domain_error("Store doesn't sell this type of item");
      }
      // Return item as a sold one
      return (*what);
   }
};

class Person {
private:
   // Person's name (identity)
   std::string name;

   // Item's that are currently possesed
   // by this person
   std::vector<Item> owned_items;

   // Amount of cash that this person has
   money_t cash;

public:
   // Note that we don't allow unnamed persons
   Person(const std::string& name, const money_t& cash = 0) : name(name), cash(cash) { }

   void Buy(const Item& what) {
      owned_items.push_back(what);
      cash -= what.price;
   }
};

void GoShopping(Person& person, const Store& store) {
   // Let's simulate buying one item

   // You could easily make a loop and determine what to buy in 
   // every loop iteration

   store.EnumerateItems();
   person.Buy(store.Sell("Shoes"));
}

int main() {
   // Initialize our store that sells only shoes
   std::vector<Item> items;
   items.push_back(Item("Shoes", 25));

   Store grocery(items);
   // Initialize our person
   Person jim_carrey("Jim Carrey", 500);

   // The yummy part
   GoShopping(jim_carrey, grocery);

   return 0;
}
```